# fable::model() pass lists of external regressors to ARIMA()

Tags: r, arima, fable-r

I would like to pass a list of models with different external regressors to
an ARIMA model within fable::model(). Ultimately, I would like to pass every possible combination of a few (up to 10) external variables to ARIMA().

Using the household budget data for the US as an example

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tsibble)
library(tsibbledata)
library(fable)
library(forecast)

aus <- hh_budget %>% 
  filter(Country == "Australia") %>% 
  select(-Country)
```

I would like to do the following without having to explicitly write the model formula

```
fit1 <- aus %>% 
  model(arima = ARIMA(Debt ~ DI))

fit2 <- aus %>% 
  model(arima = ARIMA(Debt ~ DI + Expenditure))

fit3 <- aus %>% 
  model(arima = ARIMA(Debt ~ DI + Expenditure + Savings))
```

#### I can't get model(arima = ARIMA()) to work with a changing formula.

#### Simple Example

```
target <- "Debt"
xregs <- paste0(names(aus)[3:4], collapse = " + ") %>% noquote()

fit2 <- aus %>% 
  model(arima = ARIMA(target ~ xregs))
```

#### Mapped list example

```
# Build lists of external regressor combinations

subsets_list <- function(set, subset_size) {
  combn(set, subset_size) %>%
    BBmisc::convertColsToList() %>%
    unname()
}

xregs <-
  map(.x = 1:(length(aus) - 2), .f = subsets_list, 
      set = colnames(aus[3:length(aus)])) %>% 
  unlist(recursive = F)


model_arima <- function(tsibble, target, xregs){
  model(arima = ARIMA(y = tsibble[, target], 
                      xreg = tsibble[, xregs], 
                      lambda = "auto"))
}

fit <- map(.x = xregs, 
           .f = model_arima, 
           tsibble = aus, 
           target = target)
```

#### This is how I've done it in forecast::auto.arima()

```
aus_ts <- aus %>% 
  as_tibble(.) %>% 
  select(-Year) %>% 
  ts(., start = 1995, frequency = 1)

auto_arima <- function(ts, target, xregs){
auto.arima(y = ts[, target], 
           xreg = ts[, xregs], 
           lambda = "auto")
}

fit <- map(.x = xregs, .f = auto_arima, ts = aus_ts, target = target)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create formulas programmatically in a variety of ways.
The simplest is to use `as.formula()`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(fable)
aus <- tsibbledata::hh_budget %>% 
  filter(Country == "Australia") %>% 
  select(-Country)

target <- "Debt"
xregs <- paste0(names(aus)[3:4], collapse = " + ")
as.formula(paste(target, xregs, sep ="~"))
#> Debt ~ DI + Expenditure
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Using this approach uses the parser, which has limitations for non-standard variable names. For more precise construction of formulas, you can use `rlang::new_formula()`.

To estimate your desired set of models, you can use:

```r
# Load libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(fable)

# Prepare data
aus <- tsibbledata::hh_budget %>% 
  filter(Country == "Australia") %>% 
  select(-Country)

# Construct formulas
xregs <- c("DI", "Expenditure", "Savings")
rhs <- map_chr(seq_along(xregs), ~ paste(xregs[seq_len(.)], collapse = " + "))
lhs <- "Debt"
formulas <- map(paste(lhs, rhs, sep = " ~ "), as.formula)

# Create model specifications
model_specs <- set_names(map(formulas, ARIMA), formulas)

# Estimate models
aus %>% 
  model(!!!model_specs)
#> # A mable: 1 x 3
#>                   `Debt ~ DI`   `Debt ~ DI + Expenditure`
#>                       <model>                     <model>
#> 1 <LM w/ ARIMA(1,1,0) errors> <LM w/ ARIMA(1,1,0) errors>
#> # … with 1 more variable: `Debt ~ DI + Expenditure + Savings` <model>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you @Mitchell O'Hara Wild! To still pass every possible combination of xregs I would keep my original `subsets_list` and `xregs` and then define the `rhs <- map_chr(seq_along(xregs), ~ paste(xregs[.][[1]], collapse = " + "))`

Comment: If you have a different structure for the xregs value, then you could updating that expression should work too. If it is a list of xregs to use, then `rhs <- map_chr(seq_along(xregs), ~ paste(xregs[[.]], collapse = " + "))` should be sufficient.